# loop for file location until file exists in bash

Tags: bash, file, loops, while-loop, echo

I have created this function:

```
function promptFile()

{

while true;
    do
            read -p "Please provide a full path [q to quit]: " file
            if [ $file == q ]; then
                    echo "Exiting.."
                    return 1
            fi

            if [ ! -f $file ]; then
                    echo "File does not exist, please try again"

            else
                    echo $file
                    break
            fi
    done
}
```

To prompt a user for file location, ask again if file does not exist, and save the output to a variable if it does, the function is called:

```
tempLoc=$(promptFile)
if [ !tempLoc ]; then
        fileLocation=$tempLoc
fi
```

Everything works well unless someone write a bad file location, then the echo is not shown until someone clicks q or inputs an existing file location.
in which case the echo message will be printed * the number of bad inputs, as follows.

```
[root@tsting:0]# ./tst
Please provide a full path [q to quit]: tst1
Please provide a full path [q to quit]: tst2
Please provide a full path [q to quit]: tst3
Please provide a full path [q to quit]: tst4
Please provide a full path [q to quit]: q
File does not exist File does not exist File does not exist File does not exist Exiting..
[root@tsting:0]#
```

I'm guessing this happens because the loop collapses back printing all the echos as it happens, is there a way to avoid this and just print the echo when the wrong file location is entered ?

Comment: It definitely should be printing it straight away.If you run that snippet on its own do you still have the same problem ?

Comment: Well, it is not, and i think it has something to do with the way i call the function

Comment: if i run it by itself everything is ok:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the error to stderr

```
echo "File does not exist, please try again" >&2
```

You are saving all output from the function into the variable `tempLoc`, so even if the user inputs a valid file it will have a load of junk in the variable with it.

Stderr is where error messages should go anyway though, so it's good practice to send them there even without this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explenation and the help,  the suggested code works perfectly.

Comment: @Doubleg:  you sure you tested it?  Including a quit?  Did you test it with a space in the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Several things here:

You don't need `()` with "function" (and visa versa).  `()` is usually preferred, (except in Korn shell).

ALWAYS write error messages to stderr: `>&2`, that is the main reason why it does not work.  There are TWO instances where this is required.

Nothing to do with your issue, but it is a good idea to quote variable values, especially filenames: `"$file"`. This is in case someone has whitespace in the filename. Not that anyone in their right mind would ever name a file or directory with an embedded space (Program Files).  Using `[[ ]]` rather than single brackets reduces the need, but does not remove it altogether.

Always declare variables inside functions as `local`, unless you really need to use a global (which you usually don't).  If you don't do that then the variables inside a function could stomp on those outside, particularly if you reuse the function in several scripts.

The `if` statement after calling the function is incorrect.  You are testing for true/false (which it won't be) and you have omitted a `$` prefix.

```
promptFile()
{
    local file

    while true
    do
        read -p "Please provide a full path [q to quit]: " file
        if [ "$file" == q ]; then
            echo "Exiting.." >&2
            return 1
        fi

        if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
            echo "File does not exist, please try again" >&2
        else
            echo "$file"
            break
        fi
    done
}

tempLoc=$(promptFile)
if [ -n "$tempLoc" ]; then
   fileLocation=$tempLoc
fi
```